# R startup memory usage

Tags: r

I have tried to clear the workspace using

```
rm(list=ls())
```

However,R still consumes over 2GB of RAM after each startup. Despite using the command above, R still generates the following message after startup:

> [Previously saved workspace restored]

I just want R to release all this memory. Any advice?

Comment: Delete the workspace file that's automatically being loaded ("restored"). Search for the message being printed.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware the file itself had to be manually deleted also. Solved it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be manually deleted.  You could start R with the `--no-restore-data` or `--no-restore` command line option(s).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I don't think we have this elsewhere as an answer, so it would be worth posting all of that as an answer here.

Comment: @Thomas: it's all in `?Startup`. Feel free to answer. I'm not going to re-write the documentation here. You could also mention FAQ 7.42.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that R is saving your workspace and you're reloading it into memory each time you start R.

See, for example [FAQ 7.2](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-save-my-workspace_003f):

> `save.image()` saves the objects in the user’s `.GlobalEnv` to the file .RData in the R startup directory. (This is also what happens after `q("yes")`.)

So, you're probably saving your workspace each time you exit (or you at least did it once in the past). As Joshua Ulrich writes in comments, to control this you want to look at startup options for R (see `?Startup`). As noted there, the saved workspace is loaded automatically if present:

> R then loads a saved image of the user workspace from ‘.RData’ in the current directory if there is one (unless `--no-restore-data` or `--no-restore` was specified on the command line).

So, you can either remove the saved workspace file and/or call R with those options to prevent R from loading the workspace file.

To avoid creating that file in the future choose "no" when prompted on exit (either on the command line or in the pop-up dialog window in Rgui), or call `q("no")`. You can also force this by using the `--no-save` command-line argument when you initially invoke your R session.